# eslint ignore no-undef with certain folder with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, eslint, rules

I am currently using jest to test my api calls.  I also use eslint to check codes in my test but then because using just, I do no need to define method such as `test()` or `expect()` so when I am running eslint, I would get errors such as

```
   4:1  error  'test' is not defined    no-undef
   8:3  error  'expect' is not defined  no-undef
```

but for my jest file such as `index.test.js` my code would be

```
test('API test', async () => {
  const response = await axios.post('api call', {});
  const { status, statusText, message } = response;
  expect(status).toBe(400);
  expect(statusText).toBe('Bad Request');
  expect(message).toBe('No password.');
});
```

as mentioned, I do not need to define `test()` and `expect`.  I was reading through the eslint doc but I don't seem to see a possible way to only ignore certain files not to check these rules.  I do still want to keep other rules though.

Thanks in advance for any help suggestions.

P.S. my `.eslintrc` looks like

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "env": {
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "browser": false
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": false
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "globals": {
    "strapi": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    "no-console": 0,
    "quotes": ["error", "single"],
    "semi": ["error", "always"],
    "multiline-ternary": ["error", "always"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tell `ESLint` [the environment is jest](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) `test()` and `expect()` won't be considered as undefined. And since the default test files for jest are `"**/*.spec.js", "**/__mocks__/**"` I'd suggest you to add

**`.eslintrc`**

```
{
  // your configuration
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.spec.js", "**/__mocks__/**"],
      "env": {
        "jest": true
      }
    }
  ]
```

**Edit:** You can add `"jest": true` in your global environment, but the downside is that if you accidentally use some of the jest's global functions like `describe`, `test`, `it`, `beforeAll` etc. ESLint won't report an error.

Comment: ah nice! But somehow your override does not work though.  I actually added the `"jest": true` right under `"env": {....` would work `"env": {
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "browser": false,
"jest": true
  },` would you consider changing your answer and I will mark it as correct? or what I did was actually a bad way?

Comment: @Dora it does work so I won't change my answer. You can check a [working setup here](https://github.com/Teneff/jest-workshop.git)